# Can I use a set builder with set builders inside?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Say, I have two sets defined as below.

$A = \{(x, y)\ | \ x + y > 2, \ \, x,y \in \mathbb R \}$

$B = \{(y, z)\ | \ y + z < 2, \ \, y,z \in \mathbb R \}$

Now, I'm wondering if it is possible to define a set using the predefined sets as below.

$C = \begin{equation}
\left\{
  (x, y, z) \;\middle|\;
  \begin{aligned}
  & (x, y) \in A \\
  & (y, z) \in B \\
  \end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation}
$

My goal is to define the set C with elements of $x, y,$ and $z$ simultaneously satisfying two pairwise relationships as defined in set $A$ and $B$ such that $C=\{(1, 1.1, 0), (-1.1, 4, -2.5), ...\}$.

Thanks for your advice in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can. In fact, you have done it in your first example. $\mathbb{R}$ is a predefined set, in particular, the set of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My paper will be shrunk a lot with those shorthand notations.